# Controlling which script is logged in system logs based on verbosity level in service now

Tags: servicenow

The organisation I work in uses service Now ,I just joined the team, My team wants me to do some research on logging in Service now.

All they want is to control the logging of scripts when they write a script on the server based on the verbosity level of the script

My understanding on logging  is it the type of  process that takes place on the server  i.e

•if a script is not of a proper syntax it logs as a WARNING stating the compile error in the message of the log

•If something runs successfully or a process is completed, it logs as INFO with the message of what happened

•Similar logging for debug takes place, (I may be wrong about this though)

I tried searching on service now wiki,one method I found was gs.log()

I tried running some test script to log info in  `System Definition > Scripts - Background`

Some of the various scripts I tried where

```
var gl = new GSLog("com.snc.sla.tasksla.log", "TaskSLA"); 
gl.logErr("This is an error message");


var gl = new GSLog("com.snc.sla.tasksla.log", "TaskSLA"); 
gl.logWarning("This is a warning message");

gs.info("This is an info log");
gs.debug("This is a debug log");
```

And then searched in the logs table   System Logs > System Log > All

all is saw was the scripts I ran were logged  as whole with INFO as the level , if the scripts had a syntax error it logged the same with WARNING level

Why doesn't it log the script line by line?

Also is there a way where I can tell Service now what script it should log based on the verbosity level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on the Fuji release or newer (which is still pretty new, so you may not be), there's actually a whole new logging api that's a bit more intuitive, and it's application-based. What follows is the documentation for that API:

**Verbosity**

There are 4 levels of verbosity, in order from least verbose to most verbose, they are:

```
error (gs.error)
warn (gs.warn)
info (gs.info)
debug (gs.debug)
```

...this means that setting log-level for a particular app to "info" will give you info+warn+error, but NOT debug.

...Session debugging verbosity is `debug`, so any level of log verbosity will be included in Session debug output, for JUST the app being debugged IN the session with session debugging activated.

The property for logging verbosity is (replacing  with your app name):

```
<APP_NAME>.logging.verbosity // off -> error -> warn -> info -> debug
```

**Destination**

Log destination of "db" will route log messages within desired logging verbosity to the table "syslog_app_scope", which extends syslog. This new table has added fields for the App/Scope issuing the log as well as a Source Script field that links to the script that called into the logging API (when we can figure it out, currently just for Business Rules and Script Includes). When Destination is set to "db", logs will ALSO go to file system.

Log destination of "file" will log to the node's file system log without broadcasting to log listeners (except in the case of Scripts-Background)

The property for destination is:

```
<APP_NAME>.logging.destination // none -> file -> db (implies file also)
```

**Usage Examples**

Consumers of this API (from JavaScript) should be able to just do:

`gs.debug(message [, parameters])`
-emit log message at debug level verbosity

`gs.info(message [, parameters])`
-emit log message at info level verbosity

`gs.warn(message [, parameters])`
-emit log message at warn level verbosity

`gs.error(message [, parameters])`
-emit log message at error level verbosity

This logging API supports the java MessageFormat placeholder replacement pattern
Currently there is support for up to 5 "varargs" placeholder arguments, any more than 5 need to be specified as a single javascript array argument
All of these are legal calls:

```
gs.info("Here's a log message from me"); // no params
gs.info("Here's a log message from {0}", myName); // single non array param
gs.info("Here's a log message from {0}.{1}", myFirstName, myLastName); // multiple "varargs" params (up to 5!)
gs.info("Here's a log message from {0}.{1}", [myFirstName, myLastName]); // array of n-number of params (no upper bounds)
```